# Why does unique_ptr<Derived> implicitly cast to unique_ptr<Base>?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, unique-ptr

I wrote the following code that uses `unique_ptr<Derived>` where a `unique_ptr<Base>` is expected

```
class Base {
    int i;
 public:
    Base( int i ) : i(i) {}
    int getI() const { return i; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    float f;
 public:
    Derived( int i, float f ) : Base(i), f(f) {}
    float getF() const { return f; }
};

void printBase( unique_ptr<Base> base )
{
    cout << "f: " << base->getI() << endl;
}

unique_ptr<Base> makeBase()
{
    return make_unique<Derived>( 2, 3.0f );
}

unique_ptr<Derived> makeDerived()
{
    return make_unique<Derived>( 2, 3.0f );
}

int main( int argc, char * argv [] )
{
    unique_ptr<Base> base1 = makeBase();
    unique_ptr<Base> base2 = makeDerived();
    printBase( make_unique<Derived>( 2, 3.0f ) );

    return 0;
}
```

and i expected this code to not compile, because according to my understanding `unique_ptr<Base>` and `unique_ptr<Derived>` are unrelated types and `unique_ptr<Derived>` isn't in fact derived from `unique_ptr<Base>` so the assignment shouldn't work.

But thanks to some magic it works, and i don't understand why, or even if it's safe to do so.
Can someone explain please?

Comment: smart pointers are to enrich what pointers can do not to limit it. If this wasnt possible `unique_ptr` would be rather useless in the presence of inheritance

Comment: *"But thanks to some magic it works"*. Nearly, you got UB as `Base` doesn't have virtual destructor.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The bit of magic you're looking for is the converting constructor #6 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr):

```
template<class U, class E>
unique_ptr(unique_ptr<U, E> &&u) noexcept;
```

It enables constructing a `std::unique_ptr<T>` implicitly from an expiring `std::unique_ptr<U>` *if* (glossing over deleters for clarity):

> `unique_ptr<U, E>::pointer` is implicitly convertible to `pointer`

Which is to say, it mimicks implicit raw pointer conversions, including derived-to-base conversions, and does what you expect™ safely (in terms of lifetime – you still need to ensure that the base type can be deleted polymorphically).

Comment: AFAIK the deleter of `Base` won't call the destructor of `Derived`, so I'm not sure whether it's really safe. (It's no less safe than raw pointer, admittedly.)

Answer (score 15):

Because [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) has a converting constructor as

> ```
> template< class U, class E >
> unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept;
> ```

and

> This constructor only participates in overload resolution if all of
>   the following is true:
>
> a) `unique_ptr<U, E>::pointer` is implicitly convertible to `pointer`
>
> ...

A `Derived*` could convert to `Base*` implicitly, then the converting constructor could be applied for this case. Then a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` could be converted from a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` implicitly just as the raw pointer does. (Note that the `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` has to be an rvalue for constructing `std::unique_ptr<Base>` because of the characteristic of `std::unique_ptr`.)

Answer (score 7):

You can *implicitly* construct a `std::unique_ptr<T>` instance from an *rvalue* of `std::unique_ptr<S>` whenever `S` is convertible to `T`. This is due to constructor #6 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). Ownership is transferred in this case.

In your example, you have only rvalues of type `std::uinque_ptr<Derived>` (because the return value of `std::make_unique` is an rvalue), and when you use that as a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, the constructor mentioned above is invoked. The `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` objects in question hence only live for a short amount of time, i.e. they are created, then ownership is passed to the `std::unique_ptr<Base>` object that is used further on.